# initialize 2d vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

So, I have the following code in c++:

This is the 2d vector:

```
vector<vector<int>> adj;
```

Initialization of 2d vector:

```
adj[0].push_back(1);
adj[0].push_back(2);
adj[1].push_back(3);
adj[1].push_back(4);
adj[1].push_back(5);
```

Printing the vector:

```
for(auto i : adj) {
    for(auto j : i)
        cout << j << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Compilation is without error but when I try to run it shows nothing.
How to fix this?

Comment: This probably isn't the source of your bug but `auto i : adj` will _copy_ every element in `adj` to `i`. Consider using reference-to-const: `for (const auto& i : adj)`

Comment: You fix it by opening your C++ book to the chapter that explains how `std::vector` works, paying attention to the part that the `[]` operator does not, I repeat, does not add anything to the vector, and expects the vector's contents to exist, so when you execute `ad[0]`, the vector has better have something in it already, or your program crashes. As you've discovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `adj[0]`, you're implicitly assuming that the vector has a size of at least 1, in order for the zeroth element to exist. This is not the case for an empty vector, such as a newly initialized one. Unfortunately, this does not guarantee an error of any kind, it is Undefined Behavior, and the compiler is allowed to let literally anything happen. To avoid it, you need to make room for those elements, which can be done in a number of ways:

```
adj.resize(2); // now size == 2, and [0] and [1] can be safely accessed
adj[0].push_back(1);
adj[1].push_back(3);
```

or alternatively

```
adj.push_back({}); // append default-constructed vector
adj.back().push_back(1); // append 1 to the above vector
```

or, perhaps most concisely:

```
adj = {
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4, 5}
};
// adj now contains two vectors containing {1, 2} and {3, 4, 5} respectively
```

If you want to use the subscript `[]` operator for indexed access to a vector, consider using [`vector.at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at), which performs the same functionality but throws an exception if the index is out of range. This can be very helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the size of the vector by calling its constructor:

```
vector< vector<int> > adj(row_size, vector<int>(col_size));
                             ^^^      ^^^^^^^        ^^^
                     Dimension 1    Element Ctor     Dimension 2
```

Then you can index it like an array.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector operator[] expects an element to exist.  It will result in undefined behavior if an undefined element is accessed.  Push a std::vector to the outer vector before pushing int to the inner vector.  The at() member can be used to safely access any array index with error handling.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj(2); // add two std::vector<int>


   adj[0].push_back(1);
   adj[0].push_back(2);
   adj[1].push_back(3);
   adj[1].push_back(4);
   adj[1].push_back(5);

   for(auto const & i : adj) {
       for(auto const & j : i)
          std::cout << j << " ";
       std::cout << std::endl;
   }
}
```