# Pushing back a vector of strings into a 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I am currently working in C++, dealing with string vectors.

Let's say I have a 1D string vector called 'temp.' At each index of 'temp', there is a string containing three words/chars. Let's say that temp[0] = "Hello hi 3"

I have defined a function called 'splits' which takes in some string, and removes the whitespaces, and places the result in a string vector called 'res'. So, using the 'splits' function on temp[0] results in:

```
res[0] = hello
res[1] = hi
res[2] = 3
```

I would like to use the "splits" function on each string held in 'links,' and pass it into a 2d vector of strings called 'totalResults.' As I do not know the size of 'links' I know that I will need to dynamically allocate this 2D vector of strings.

So far I have:

```
vector<vector<string>> totalResults //dynamically allocated 2d vector of strings

vector<string> temp;

for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++)

{
    
    for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++)

    {
        temp=splits(links[j])
        totalResults[i][j].push_back(temp[0][j])); 
    
        //using splitting function on links[i], and pushing it into the 2d vector
    
    
    }

}
```

In this example, I would like "hello" to go into totalResults[0][0], "hi" to go into totalResults[0][1], and "3" to go into totalResults[0][2].
In the second row of totalResults, I would like the same assignment to occur, but when 'splits' is used on 'links[1]'.

I have testing the 'splits' function in isolation, and it works as I expect it to, so I am assuming the error may be in how I am pushing back values into this 2d vector. I am testing the resulting 2D matrix, but nothing is printing... Are the values not actually being pushed in?

I appreciate any help/ideas!
Thank you! :)

Comment: I suggest to start with a vector of strings and push some strings to them, because once you got 1D straight, 2D is not ^2 more complicated, but just *2 the same. The problem in your code would be the same/similar with 1D only

Comment: *"I will need to dynamically allocate this 2D vector of strings."* -- no you will not. One of the major reasons for using `std::vector` is so that you do **not** need to dynamically allocate anything as the `vector` handles that behind the scenes. (Fortunately, your code shows no attempt to perform a dynamic allocation.)

Comment: `totalResults[i][j].push_back(temp[0][j])); ` adds one character to a string, which isn't what you want.

Comment: Hi @molbdnilo, is it adding one character to the string as a result of the indexing that I have done? As opposed to the push_back() function itself?

Comment: The code you have so far has numerous syntactical errors, which prevent it from compiling. Also see [initialize 2d vector in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52600722) as you work on a syntactically correct [mre].

Comment: @Angela `totalResults` is a vector of vector of strings, so `totalResults[i][j]` is a string. `temp` is a vector of strings, so `temp[0]` is a string, and `temp[0][j]` is a character.

Comment: It's not very clear what `rows` and `cols` are. Do you *really* want the same thing in each `totalResults[i]`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, `links` has `cols` elements, and you want to split each `links[j]` and add it to `totalResults`:

```
vector<vector<string>> totalResults(cols);
for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
{
    totalResults[j] = splits(links[j]); 
}
```